# Merging DEMs of different grid size

Tags: qgis, dem, merge, saga

I'm trying to merge two grids with different cell size. One has a cell size of 10m and the other 50m. The 10m one covers a subarea of the 50m one. I know that the most accurate one is the 10m one and hence I would like to keep its values in the overlapping areas, and not do any kind of interpolation. My problem is that the resulting merged grid (after resampling the 50m grid to 10m) has obvious step changes as seen in the picture

[image: Merged grid]

Is there a way I can feather out these discrepancies without editing the grids cell by cell? I'm using Qgis and Saga.

Thanks

Comment: Please embed images directly in the question (it preserves the integrity of the question over time).

Comment: Did the DEMs come from vector contours in the first place?

Answer (score 3):

Just in case anybody else would be interested on this the best way I could find was using saga gis software module Mosaicking. The module has two options 'blend boundary' and 'feathering'

[image]

Comment: could you post the resulting image for comparison?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it to be bad practice to down scale your rasters (the 50m to 10m)...Here is some helpful info about resampling rasters
http://www.indiana.edu/~gisci/courses/g338/lectures/introduction_raster.html
Also, what resampling technique are you using?

Comment: I don't think that the problem is the resampling method. I'm using bilinear Interpolation, but any method I use will end up in discrepancies.